# Изменить условие INNER JOIN, если будет NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

Чисто для вашего понимания напишу рандомные таблицы:

```
(lesson)        (teacher)
id|name          id|name
1 |Математика    1 |Дудина П.П.
2 |Русский       2 |Липова З.З.
3 |Физика        3 |Дроздова К.К.

(lesson_teacher)
id|lesson_id|teacher_id
1 |    1    |     1
2 |    2    |   NULL
3 |    3    |     3

SELECT * FROM lesson_teacher
INNER JOIN lesson ON lesson_teacher.lesson_id = lesson.id
INNER JOIN teacher ON lesson_teacher.teacher_id = teacher.id
WHERE lesson.name = "Русский"
```

По этому примеру мне нужно вывести всю строку, где lesson.name = "Русский" (2), но тут не выводит ничего.
Я конечно понимаю что ничего не выводит из-за установки "INNER JOIN teacher" и указания условия "lesson_teacher.teacher_id = teacher.id", но мне после получения этой выборки нужно вывести этого преподавателя, а без INNER JOIN это не получится сделать, я думал может как-то через IF сделать?

Comment: Используйте LEFT JOIN вместо INNER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как у этой записи в качестве ссылки на учителя стоит NULL, то и выводить нечего. Если необходимо вывести всю строку, с отсутствующим значением, то необходимо переписать код запроса под `LEFT JOIN`. Например так:

```
SELECT * FROM lesson_teacher
  LEFT JOIN lesson ON
lesson_teacher.lesson_id = lesson.id
LEFT JOIN teacher ON
lesson_teacher.teacher_id = teacher.id
WHERE lesson.name = "Русский"
```